# Rowspan cell not the same size

Tags: html, css

I have a simple `table` with `rowspan` . I need to that cell number1,  cell number2 and cell number6 to be the same size .
How can I achieve that please

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>number1</td>
    <td>number3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">number2</td>
    <td>number4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>number5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>number6</td>
    <td>number7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your table makes very little sense...How many rows and how many columns?

Comment: You want cell two to take up two rows, but be the same size as two other rows?

Comment: I need 2 columns and  3 rows .if you copy the code to HTML editor you see in column 1 ,cells number1 number2 number6 not the same size number2 the height size is bigger because of the rowspan. I need the same size for cell number 1,2,6 and still use rowspan

Comment: Check my answer, let me know if that is what you were after.

Answer (score 1):

Like this you mean?

This solution uses the existing markup, no need for any "empty" rows.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}
tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child,
tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child,
tr:nth-child(4) td:first-child {
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>number1</td>
    <td>number3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">number2</td>
    <td>number4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>number5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>number6</td>
    <td>number7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to add a single cell row under each row that has a rowspan. So basically, you need to accommodate room for any span in a table, otherwise you'll get extra cells protruding from the table. Easiest way to remember is to:

> Make one less cell for every unit of the (rowspan -1) on each proceeding row.
>
> Make one less cell for every unit of the (colspan -1) on each proceeding column.

```css
table {
  width: 105px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
tr {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Col1, 2, & 6</title>
  <style>
    table {
      1px solid grey
    }
    td {
      border: 1px solid black
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1</td>
      <td rowspan="2">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">6</td>
      <td rowspan="2">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: look at my code I need that cell number3 same as number4+number5 and same as number7

Comment: *I need the same size for cell number 1,2,6 and still use rowspan* Forget the labels, is that the shape of the table you wanted?

Comment: <table>
  <tr>
    <td>CELL</td>
    <td>CELL</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">CELL</td>
    <td>CELL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>CELL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>CELL</td>
    <td>CELL</td>
  </tr>
 </table>

Comment: This the shape I need but all the size of the cells on the left column are not the same

Comment: In the left column the cells are of equal size. In the right column the cells are of equal size. Are you looking at the demo? Click the "Run Code Snippet " button.

Comment: Are you aware of what `rowspan` is? [Read this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp) When you said: * I need the same size for cell number 1,2,6 and still use rowspan*, that means you want the left column cells twice the height of the cells in the right column.

Comment: I am not big expert of HTML :) thanks then I will think of a different solution then and not rowspan probably.

Comment: Not sure how I can do it. What I need on the left side 3 cells and 3 cells on the right side  but the middle cell one on the right should be split into 2 cell and size height of the 2 cell together that was spited should be the same size as all the other cells

Comment: Sounds like 3 cells on the left and 4 cells on the right. If you are really set on having 3 cells to the right... then the whole table will not be a square.

Comment: it should be. that is my problem . in the cells in the middle, the left cell width  should be equal to the width of the 2 cells combine  on the right side in the middle and then the table be square

Comment: @Alex2016 Updated, please review, I think I got it (crossed fingers). If this isn't it, you'll need to show me an image.

Comment: Thank you for the sample

Comment: Your'e very welcome. Does it meet your requirements? I had a hard time visualizing what you described.